# Problem with a single line code of random digit number

Tags: python

I took this line from online to make a random 4 digit number

```
number = str(random.randint(0,9999))
```

but sometimes it give me random 3 digit number why?

Is their a better way to make a random multiple digit number in python

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) of `randint`? It says: *Return a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`.* So in your code `0` is also an option. It is not 4 digits. Try `randint(1000,9999)`

Comment: You should read the base knowledge about random.randint(a, b) - Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1). Detail here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's arguable that most of the answers in the question for which this is marked a duplicate of could be superseded by using `random.choices()`.

Comment: @mhawke and? I don't see your point. This is still an obvious duplicate. If you have another solution not existing there, feel free to post it there

Comment: @Tomerikoo: fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've asked for a number between 0 and 9999 inclusive. That includes single, double and triple digit numbers as well.

If you want only 4 digit numbers start at 1000:

```
number = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
```

See the [`randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.randint) documentation.

If you want 4 digits that could include leading zeroes then you use `random.choices()`:

```
from string import digits

number = ''.join(random.choices(digits, k=4))
```

which picks 4 digits with replacement and joins them into a string.

Comment: `choices` could give something like `0123` which might not be an acceptable option...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: or it might be acceptable, difficult to tell from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
```

Comment: A short explanation (maybe a link) could also improve your answer